# UBB Code [textarea] - do not replace \n by <br> within tags [textarea][/textarea]

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

I currently load a value from my database straight into a hidden textarea.

```
<textarea name="text" id="text" style="visibility:hidden">
[textarea]Content showing raw [b]HTML[/b] or any other code
Including line breaks </a>[/textarea]
</textarea>
```

From there I pick up the textarea's content and run it trough several replace arguments with a simple Javascript, like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function parser() {  
    post_text=post_text.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br>"); 
    post_text=post_text.replace(/\[size=1\]/g, "<span style=\"font-size:80%\">"); 
    post_text=post_text.replace(/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/g, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>&nbsp;<img src=\"images/link.gif\" style=\"border:0px\">");
    post_text=post_text.replace(/\[url\](.+?)\[\/url\]/g, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>&nbsp;<img src=\"images/link.gif\" style=\"border:0px\">");

document.getElementById('vorschau').innerHTML = post_text; 
}, false);
</script>

<div id="vorschau"></div>
```

to render it into HTML which is then parsed by the Browser, so I do all the formatting of the entries on the Frontend/client side.

However, the textarea may also contain such an UBB tag:

```
[textarea]Content showing raw [b]HTML[/b] or any other code
Including line breaks </a>[/textarea]
```

I currently just replace the textarea UBB elements like any other content

```
post_text=post_text.replace(/\[textarea\]/g, "<textarea id=\"codeblock\" style=\"width:100%;min-height:200px;\">");
post_text=post_text.replace(/\[\/textarea\]/g, "</textarea>");
```

The issue with this is that my other code

```
post_text=post_text.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br>");
post_text=post_text.replace(/\</g, "&lt;");
post_text=post_text.replace(/\>/g, "&gt;");
```

Does not skip the content within the [textarea][/textarea] elements resulting in a textarea filled with this:

```
Content showing raw <b>HTML</b> or any other code<br>Including line breaks &lt;/a&gt;
```

[Above example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXqu3.jpg)

**So how do I prevent to replace anything within [textarea][/textarea] (which can occur more than once in id="text")?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do, is use a dynamic pattern that captures from `[textarea]` till `[/textarea]` in group 1, and use an alternation to match what you want to replace.

Then use a callback function for replace. Check if group 1 exists, and if it does return it unmodified. If it does not, we have a match outside of the text area.

An example of the pattern with the alternation and match for `<`

```
(\[textarea][^]*\[\/textarea])|<
```

- `(\[textarea][^]*\[\/textarea])` Capture **group 1**, match from `[textarea]` till `[/textarea]`
- `|` Or
- `<` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RDgOJm/1)

**Note** to double escape the backslash in the RegExp constructor.

(Assuming this is the right order of replacements:)

```js
const replacer = (text, find, replace) => text.replace(
  new RegExp(`(\\[textarea][^]*\\[\\/textarea])|${find}`, "g"),
  (m, g1) => g1 ? g1 : replace
);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function parser() {

  let post_text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  post_text = post_text.replace(/\[size=1]/g, "<span style=\"font-size:80%\">");
  post_text = post_text.replace(/\[url=(.+?)](.+?)\[\/url\]/g, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>&nbsp;<img src=\"images/link.gif\" style=\"border:0px\">");
  post_text = post_text.replace(/\[url](.+?)\[\/url]/g, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>&nbsp;<img src=\"images/link.gif\" style=\"border:0px\">");
  post_text = replacer(post_text, "\\r?\\n", "<br>");
  post_text = replacer(post_text, "<", "&lt;");
  post_text = replacer(post_text, ">", "&gt;");
  post_text = post_text.replace(/\[textarea]/g, "<textarea id=\"codeblock\" style=\"width:100%;min-height:200px;\">");
  post_text = post_text.replace(/\[\/textarea]/g, "</textarea>");

  document.getElementById('vorschau').innerHTML = post_text;
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="text" rows="10" cols="60">
[textarea]Content showing raw [b]HTML[/b] or any other code
Including line breaks </a>[/textarea]
    
    
    < here and > here and
</textarea>

<div id="vorschau"></div>
```

Comment: I know I shouldn't according to Stackoverflow, but thank you so much, The fourth bird! This works exactly as I wanted it. Thanks for providing a working code which makes it way easier for me to understand how to achieve it in further projects.